# disable chrome debugging. Cordova 5.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome

Is there a way to disable the Chrome Debugging of an app?

when I do chrome://inspect my app is listed eventhough, I downloaded the app from the play store. The app is also build under --release state and signed.

Any help?

Comment: What if the app breaks and a user needs to unbreak it via the debugger?

Comment: I don't think regular users need access or will understand how to debug. I don't really care about securing the source files, but I don't also want it to make it too easy for copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give the `android:debuggable=["true" | "false"]` a shot in your manifest.  This is an attribute for the application tag, and you can manually append it in the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml file.

Or, you could do this via a cordova hook.  See this hook from an ionic generator: https://github.com/djett41/generator-ionic/blob/master/templates/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js

Hooks can be automatically run from the hooks folder, and this particular hook would reside in hooks/after_prepare, or in the config as `<hook type="after_prepare" src="path/to/file/update_platform_config.js" />`

More documentation on hooks can be found in the hooks readme: https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/blob/master/hooks/README.md

Running this option using the hook listed above, you would add something along these lines to your config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-debuggable" value="false" />` 
</platform>
```

Comment: cordova 5.0 doesn't allow the parameter debuggable=true|false, it says it is handled automatically between --debug and --release. But both are accessible in chrome://inspect. I also tried the hook, but also didn't work for me.

Comment: I am having same problem.  -debug and --release version are still accessible via Chrome Inspector.  Great for pre-release and debugging but I don't want code/resources exposed in the release version.  I am on Cordova 6.0.0

Comment: @rolinger, I'm having the same problem. Were you able to figure this out?